# Must the conjugate transpose of an idempotent matrix be idempotent?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $A \in M_{n×n}(C)$ be idempotent. Is $A^H$ necessarily idempotent?

I think it's true. As $A$ is idempotent then $A^T$ is idempotent. So, the answer is yes when the field is $\mathbb{R}$. However I am not sure about $A^H$ when $A \in M_{n×n}(C)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conjugacy is a $\mathbb{R}$-multiplicative morphism, then conjugate transpose is a antimorphism. Therefore, if $AA=A$, one has
$$
A^HA^H=(AA)^H=A^H
$$
which is the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

If $A^2=A$, then $(A^H)^2 = A^H A^H = (A^2)^H = A^H$.